# Solve: $x^2\equiv 1 \pmod{20},x^2\equiv 6 \pmod{15},x^2\equiv 9 \pmod{18}.$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I want to solve: $x^2\equiv 1 \pmod{20}, x^2\equiv 6 \pmod {15}, x^2\equiv 9\pmod{18}.$ This is a system of congruence equations, but these are not linear and moduli are not coprime. So,we cannot apply chinese remainder theorem here. However, I think I can solve for $y\equiv 1 \pmod{20}, y\equiv 6 \pmod{15}, y\equiv 9 \pmod{18}$ by using extended chinese remainder theorem,then we have to search for the square numbers out of them.How to do that?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130470/discussion-on-question-by-kishalay-sarkar-solve-x2-equiv-1-pmod20-x2-equi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{5} \iff x \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{5}$$
$$x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{4} \iff x \equiv 1,3 \pmod{4}$$
$$x^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{9} \iff x \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$$

Comment: would you mind explaining it sufficiently??

Comment: @Spectre $p$ prime, then $x^2 \equiv a^2 \pmod{p} \iff p|x^2-a^2 \iff p|(x-a)(x+a) \iff p|x-a$ or $p|x+a \iff x \equiv \pm a \pmod{p}$  by Euclid's lemma.

Comment: @Adola Now how to solve these equations,we need to consider $4$ different cases and solve?

Comment: @KishalaySarkar. Yes. There's a shortcut on two cases.


Case 1: x = 1 mod 5, x = 1 mod 4, x = 0 mod 3
then from the first and second, x = 1 mod 20. combining with x = 0 mod 3 we have x = 21 mod 60
Case 2: x = -1 mod 5, x = -1 mod 4, x = 0 mod 3
then from the first and second, x = -1 mod 20. combining with x = 0 mod 3 we have x = 39 mod 60

Answer (score 3):

Let $m,n,k,r,s\in\mathbb Z_{≥0}^{+}$ then we have,

$$\begin{cases}x^2=20m+1\\ x^2=15n+6\\ x^2=18k+9\end{cases}$$

**First restriction:**

$$\begin{align} &15n+6=18k+9\\
\implies &5n+2=6k+3\\
\implies &5(n-k)-k=1\\
\implies &k+1=5r\\
\implies &k=5r-1\\
\implies &n=6r-1\\
\end{align}$$

**Second restriction:**

$$\begin{align}&20m+1=90r-9\\
\implies &20m=10(9r-1)\\
\implies &2m=r+8r-1\\
\implies &r-1=2s\\
\implies &r=2s+1 \\
\implies &m=9s+4\end{align}$$

We conclude that,

$$\begin{align}&m=9s+4\\
&n=12s+5\\
&k=10s+4\end{align}$$

This implies,

$$\begin{align}&x^2=180s+81=9(20s+9)\\\
\implies &u^2=20s+9,\thinspace u\in\mathbb Z^{+}.\end{align}$$

**Final answer:**

Let $u=20m-n; m,n\in\mathbb Z^{+}$ with $0<n<20$ (we can also write: $x=20m±n; m,n\in\mathbb Z^{+}$ with $0<n<10$)

Then we have,

$$\begin{align}(20m-n)^2-9&\equiv n^2-9\\
&\equiv 0 \thinspace \thinspace \thinspace \text{(mod 20)}\end{align}$$

We see that the number $n^2$ must end with $9$. Thus, we can restrict the $n$, such that

$$n\in\left\{3,7,13,17\right\}$$

Therefore, we obtain the all possible solutions as follows:

$$x=60m-3n,\thinspace n\in\left\{3,7,13,17\right\}.$$

Comment: This is not a clever way I think.

Comment: Note that, no calculations are required at the end. The number $n$ must end with $9$. From here we get the possible set $n\in\left\{3,7,13,17\right\}.$ Thus, it is enough to check these mumbers.

Comment: Yes, this is very good!

Comment: @TereseLisbon Thank you very much for taking your time to review.  This is very precious to me.   $( ◜‿◝ )$